# How to make so that Jade (Node.js) doesn't close the <body> tag

Tags: node.js, pug, template-engine

I'm trying to send multiple chunks of data to a client each of which is rendered by Jade templating engine in Express Node.js framework.

1. I have several views like header, viewA, viewB, viewC, etc.
2. For every request I need to render the header partial view and send it as a chunk so that the client browser starts rendering it. When the header view is rendered I don't want the `<body>` tag inside to be closed, because more data is to come which should be inside the `<body>` tag.
3. In the meantime, I need to do some computations and after that render another view: either A, B, or C.
4. Once A, B, or C view is sent, I close the response which means closing the `</body></html>` tags.

Sounds very simple. But the problem is that Jade closes the `<html>` and `<body>` tags when rendering the header view.

I know how to do this manually using native Node.js response object, however, can't figure out how to do this with Jade the right way.

The only solution I currently see is to manually send the header part down to open `<body>` tag, then render the rest as Jade partials via `res.partial()`.

Any hint is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can output any text (including raw html) with `!=`

```
!= "<body>"
  some
     more
        tree(attr=1)
```

Result in this output:

```
<body>
<some>
  <more>
    <tree attr="1"></tree>
  </more>
</some>
```

Comment: Which version of Jade this should work in? I have 0.26.3, and the above syntax didn't work: compilation error.

Comment: Right, that's what I did. Please add the minimum version requirement, and I will accept your answer. Thank you!

Comment: its in the documentation at least 2 years - https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/commit/8eef32c5877e582d7943cd39075b7f364a6c82f3 . ( v0.22.1 should be enough ) Are you sure that you have version older than 2 years?

Answer (score 0):

Even though I may accept the above answer which seems to have worked but haven't. Nevertheless, the following code did work.

```
!!! 5
<html>
head
    meta(http-equiv="Content-Type",content="text/html;charset=utf-8")
    meta(http-equiv="Cache-Control", content="no-cache")
    meta(http-equiv="Expires", content="0")
    title= title
    link(rel="shortcut icon",href='/img/nelo2_logo.ico')
    link(rel='stylesheet',href='/css/bootstrap.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet',href='/css/jquery-ui.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet',href='/css/chosen.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet',href='/css/common.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet',href='/css/style.css')
    script(src='/js/core/require.js')
<body>
```

So the solution was not to indent the `<html>` and `<body>` tags but have them on the same column. This way Jade doesn't close them.